# Red Anthurium leaf damage and how to encourage blooms

Tags: diagnosis

I have had this red anthurium for 5 years and I was wondering if there is a way to make it bloom more. It is next to a window so it receives a lot of light and I water it once a week. What should I use to encourage more blooms?
Also if anyone could tell what is wrong with its leaves?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dead brown center surrounded by new yellowing tissue on older growth is characteristic of a fungus virus bacteria brought on by overwatering.   This plant looks very healthy.  Try these tips

- verify the soil drains freely but has a high organic content.   Spaghnum moss works well. Repot if necessary
- move to a higher but diffuse light, behind light curtain facing south
- fertilize  with flowering plant fertilizer at half strength for three months and see what happens